# Particle system running slowly

Tags: three.js, particle-system

here is update function. As soon as i turn update on my program gets slower. I'm not even able to render 25000 particles at a time. Voxels is a 3 dimensional array. How to i change my update function so that the calculations is done faster. i want to able to render at least 100000 particles.

```
function update(){

newTime = Date.now();
elapsedTime = newTime - oldTime;
oldTime = newTime;


for(var index =0 ; index < particles.vertices.length; index++){

    //particle's old position
    var oldPosition = particles.vertices[index];

    //making sure particles do not og out of boundary 
    if (oldPosition.x > screenSquareLength || oldPosition.x < -screenSquareLength){
        oldPosition.x =  2 * screenSquareLength * Math.random() - screenSquareLength;
    }
    if (oldPosition.y > screenSquareLength || oldPosition.y < -screenSquareLength){
        oldPosition.y =  2 * screenSquareLength * Math.random() - screenSquareLength;   
    }
    if (oldPosition.z > screenSquareDepth/2 || oldPosition.z < -screenSquareDepth/2){
        oldPosition.z =  screenSquareDepth * Math.random() - screenSquareDepth/2;
    }


    var oldVelocity = particlesExtraInfo[index].velocity;
    var fieldVelocity;
    var xIndex, yIndex, zIndex;


    try{
        //calculating index of voxel
        xIndex = Math.floor(( oldPosition.x + screenSquareLength ) / voxelSize);
        yIndex = Math.floor(( oldPosition.y  + screenSquareLength ) / voxelSize);
        zIndex = Math.floor(( screenSquareDepth / 2  - oldPosition.z) / voxelSize);


        //getting velocity, color for particle  and if voxel is
        fieldVelocity = voxels[zIndex][xIndex][yIndex].userData["velocity"];
        particleColor = voxels[zIndex][xIndex][yIndex].userData["color"];
        activeVoxel = voxels[zIndex][xIndex][yIndex].userData["visible"];

    }catch (e){
        console.log("indexX = "+xIndex + " \t Yindex = "+ yIndex+" \t zIndex = "+ zIndex);
    }


    var particleColor;
    var activeVoxel;



    try{

        var vx = ((oldVelocity.x + fieldVelocity.x) * elapsedTime);
        var vy = ((oldVelocity.y + fieldVelocity.y) * elapsedTime);
        var vz = ((oldVelocity.z + fieldVelocity.z) * elapsedTime);
        var magnitude = Math.abs(vx) + Math.abs(vy) + Math.abs(vz); //Math.sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy+ vz*vz);
        var normalized = new THREE.Vector3(vx / magnitude, vy / magnitude, vz / magnitude);



        if((particles.vertices[index].x < 0.1 && particles.vertices[index].x > -0.1) && (particles.vertices[index].y < 0.1 && particles.vertices[index].y > -0.1) && (particles.vertices[index].z < 0.1 && particles.vertices[index].z > -0.1) ){
            particles.vertices[index].x = 2 * screenSquareLength * Math.random() - screenSquareLength;;
            particles.vertices[index].y = 2 * screenSquareLength * Math.random() - screenSquareLength;;
            particles.vertices[index].z = 2 * screenSquareLength * Math.random() - screenSquareLength;;
        }



        //if voxel is not part of the model update particle postion and velocity
        if( activeVoxel == 0){
            particles.colors[index] = new THREE.Color(particleColor);//new THREE.Color(0, 0, 1);
            particles.colorsNeedUpdate = true;

            particles.vertices[index].x += normalized.x/slowingFactor;
            particles.vertices[index].y += normalized.y/slowingFactor;
            particles.vertices[index].z += normalized.z/slowingFactor;
            particles.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
            particlesExtraInfo[index].velocity = normalized;
        }else{
            //voxel is part of particle so update color property of particle
            particles.colors[index] = new THREE.Color(0, 0, 1);
            particles.colorsNeedUpdate = true;



            particles.vertices[index].x += normalized.x/(slowingFactor * 200);
            particles.vertices[index].y += normalized.y/(slowingFactor * 200);
            particles.vertices[index].z += normalized.z/(slowingFactor * 200);

            particles.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

            particlesExtraInfo[index].velocity = new THREE.Vector3( normalized.x/slowingFactor, normalized.y/slowingFactor, normalized.z/slowingFactor );

        }
    }catch(e){

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about what exactly happens when you update a buffer like this, but I know that it can be slow.

While 25k may be a lot for what you're trying to do (i experimented with 5k and had trouble) there is no reason why you can't optimize your JS before trying to move everything to the gpu (for example).

```
var foo = 0;

foo+= normalized.x / someFactor;

//better done this way:
var invSomeFactor = 1/someFactor;

// now you avoid dividing the same thing many times in your loop
foo += normalized.x * invSomeFactor;
```

Math.random() is pretty expensive, you could make a look up table (a large one) and fetch these precomputed values from it.

```
var myLookupTable = [];
var MAX_VALUES = 2048;

for ( var i = 0 ; i < MAX_VALUES ; i ++ ){
     myLookupTable.push(Math.random());
}

//and then you can have a stride for example
var RAND_STRIDE = 0;

//and in the loop
    someVec.x += something.x * myLookupTable[ RAND_STRIDE ++ ];

    RAND_STRIDE %= MAX_VALUES; //read from the beginning
```

Finally, you can write a fragment shader, that would read from a buffer, and write into another buffer doing all this logic in the process. Each fragment is your particle and once you run this pass and compute your positions, you need to be able to read the buffer in your particle vertex shader and just assign those positions.